# Unable to Create Cloudant NoSQL DB in IBM Internal Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

When I attempt to create a Cloudant NoSQL DB in IBM Internal Bluemix, I receive the following message and the Service Name field is disabled. Is there a way to create a Cloudant NoSQL DB in IBM Internal Bluemix?

Message:
��VJ-*�/R�R��+I-�K�QN-*K-Rp��(��'e�d��U9�)d��u*�''���(���j L

Comment: As a public forum, Stack Overflow is not a good channel for discussing internal IBM issues. Please create a ticket as Chris suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you persistently receive an error message when trying to create a service instance of Cloudant in Bluemix, you should raise a support ticket.